# Switching views with a sidebar and a horizontal SashForm

Tags: java, swt, sidebar

I need an idea to solve the following problem:
I want to build a main window with a sidebar and different views.
The sidebar consists of a list component with several entries. By selecting one of these entries I want to switch the view in the right part of the window. For that reason I can add a selection listener for the list and then show or hide the views. For the views I would use composites.

Now I have the idea to use a horizntal SashForm to split the window: In the left part I would place the sidebar and in the right part I would place the view.
But then I have to remove and add composites whenever an entry in the sidebar list is selected because the SashForm can only have two children.
How is this possible or is there any better way to realize my GUI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just use `Composite` for each child of the `SashForm`. The `Composite` can then contain any other controls you like.

There are many ways to show / hide controls, for example you might use `StackLayout`.